# NSTableView reload data from different controller

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nstabview

I am having problems updating the content of two tables, which are placed in two different tabs of a `NSTabView` and each controlled by a different controller (Controller1 and Controller3), from a third controller (Controller2).
I tried three different approaches:

Approach #1:
I created in Controller1 (the controller of the table `invitesTableView`) the method refreshTable :

```
- (void)refreshTable {
  invites = //fill my mutable array
  NSLog(@"%@",invites); 
  [self.invitesTableView reloadData];
  NSLog(@"invite's table view updated");
}
```

which I later call from Controller2 doing :

```
Controller1 *controller1 = [[Controller1 alloc] init];
[controller1  refreshTable];
```

`NSLog` prints the content of the array invites correctly, but the table is not updated. I should say that, at application launch, I call the very same method in Controller1 and the content of the array invites is correctly loaded in the table.

Approach #2: When in Controller2 I do:

```
Controller1 *controller1 = [[Controller1 alloc] init];
controller1.invites = //fill my mutable array
NSLog(@"%@",controller1.invites);
[controller1.invitesTableView reloadData];
```

But again the content of the table is not updated, even if the `NSLog` shows the correct content.

Approach #3: As Controller1 controls the content of a `NSTabViewItem`, I integrated in Controller1 the method:

```
- (void)tabView:(NSTabView *)tabView didSelectTabViewItem:(NSTabViewItem *)inviteTab
```

and it works just fine, because I call the method `refreshTable` as soon as open the tab controlled by Controller1. The problem is that I have different tables in different tabs but I can set only one controller as the delegate of the `NSTabView`, so I can not update the table controlled by Controller3 in a different table.
I don't think there is an easy solution to approach #3, apart from merging Controller1 and Controller3, but I think I am just missing something with respect to the first two approaches.

Hope I explained myself clearly. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use notifications/observer to reload tableview.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(reloadTable:)
                                             name:@"reloadNotification"
                                           object:nil];

- (void)reloadTable:(NSNotification *)notif {
    [self.tableName reloadData];
}
```

In your first tab use this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadNotification" 
                                                    object:nil];
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, it will be very handy. Thanks Anoop Vaidya!

Comment: It did work yes! But I can't vote yet, I do not have enough reputation :(